# ubuntu 18.04 is not accepting cron job

Tags: cron, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to set a cron job in ubuntu18.04 but it is giving me error of command not found

```
root@UB-Machine:~# * * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
Machine: command not found
```

I have tried restarting cron but still i am getting same error

Comment: It looks like you're typing `* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` at the shell prompt. Each `*` expands to the list of files in your corrent directory; the first is apparently called `Machine`. You need to use the `crontab` command to create a cron job. `man crontab` for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is working now.